# Print Custom ID for Each Custom Post based on Term

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'project', 'posts_per_page' => -1)); ?>
<?php while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
    <?php
    $i = 1;
    $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'tagportfolio');
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        ?>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 mix
             <?php echo $term->name . ' ' . $i; ?> ">
            <div class="pdf-thumb-box">  <a class="fancybox-media" href="<?php the_field('url'); ?>">
                    <div class="pdf-thumb-box-overlay">
                        <span>
                            <?php the_title(); ?>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('medium'); ?>">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
        $i++;
    }
    ?>
    <?php
endwhile;
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

I want to print the name and custom ID of each custom post based by name.

- Get all custom posts with name `project`
- Get each term
- For each term echo the value of `$i`
- Increment value of `$i`
- If a new term reset value of `$i` to `0`

Comment: what do you mean by `If a new term reset`?

Comment: if a new term name. basically wanna ad a unique id to all terms with with the same name and then reset

Comment: terms already have unique IDs

Comment: if the posts belongs to term "animation" the loop should echo a unique id for each post.

 <div class="1 animation"></div> <div class="2 animation">

when a new term is introduced "music" reset the count and start over

 <div class="1 music"></div> <div class="2 music>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

```
<?php 
$terms = get_terms( array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'tagportfolio'
                ) );

foreach($terms as $term) {
    $i = 1;
    $loop = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'project', 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'order' => 'ASC', 'posts_per_page' => -1,'tax_query' => array( array('taxonomy' => 'tagportfolio', 'field' => 'id', 'terms' => $term->term_id)))); 
    while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();   ?>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 mix <?php echo $term->name . ' ' . $i; ?> ">
                <div class="pdf-thumb-box">  
                    <a class="fancybox-media" href="<?php the_field('url'); ?>">
                        <div class="pdf-thumb-box-overlay">
                            <span>
                                <?php the_title(); ?>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('medium'); ?>">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php $i++; ?>
        <?php
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_query();
}
?>
```